# Render QWidget to PDF with selectable text

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.15

Assume a `QWidget` as a container for other widgets. The widgets in this container are a widget with layout `QVBoxLayout` that should show two columns of `QLabel`. After that there comes a new widget which is a `QTableView`.

I now would like to render the above described widget to a PDF file with selectable text. For now i set up my `QPrinter` and the correspoinding `QPainter` with

```
QPrinter* printer = new QPrinter(selectedPrinterInfo, QPrinter::ScreenResolution);
printer->setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4));
printer->setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
printer->setFullPage(true);
printer->setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer->setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer->setPageMargins(QMarginsF(15,15,15,15),QPageLayout::Unit::Millimeter);
printer->setOutputFileName(fileName);
printer->setResolution(300);

QPainter painter(printer);
```

now i render my widget with

```
myWidget->render(&painter);
```

this creates a nice PDF of a good quality, but it is only a image withing a pdf file. The text is not selectable. My approach for making it selectable was first render `myWidget` to `QPicture` and then replay it to `QPainter`

```
QPicture picture;
myWidget->render(&picture);
painter.drawPicture(0,0,picture);
```

Which creates a PDF that **HAS** selectable text. My problem with this approach `QPicture` has serious problems with correctly displaying this table. E.g. i set `AlternatingRowColors` to `true` and now the rowcolors overlap the grid lines. So is there any approach for rendering a `QWidget` directly with `QPainter` as PDF, or any other approach todo this without using `QPicture`